# Looping through List elements in order to build an array to pass out in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, httpwebrequest

I want to pass a bunch of data out to my server.

So i have a bunch of Lists like so:

```
<ul id="myList">
<li><span class="firstData">10</span><span id="secondData">banana</span></li>
<li><span class="firstData">20</span><span id="secondData">grapefruit</span></li>
<li><span class="firstData">30</span><span id="secondData">apple</span></li>
<li><span class="firstData">40</span><span id="secondData">pear</span></li>
<ul>
```

I want to loop through the list and create data in the form '`firstDataValue_secondDataValue`' so i can build up a string to pass out in my POST ajax request.

something like `value=10_banana&amp;value=20_grapefruit&amp` and so on.

How best can i loop through the elements in order to create the string of data i'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're aware that duplicate `id` s are invalid, right? Use a `class` instead. =)

Comment: IDs should be unique, if you need a repeated identifier, use a `class` instead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul#myList li').each(function(){
//do what you want here
   var number = $(this).find('span:first-child').text();
   var fruit = $(this).find('span:first-last').text();
//now you have both values do whatever you want with it
});
```

that will loop for every li element

Answer (score 0):

This should build up the string formatted the way you requested based on HTML you provided but changing `id` to `class` as suggested in comments to the question: [Working example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/6V65k/)

```
var str = '';
$('ul#myList li').each(function(){
    var spans = $(this).find('span');
    str += 'value='+spans[0].innerHTML+'_'+spans[1].innerHTML+'&amp;';
});
```